# Is this lower bound for a norm of some complex matrices true?

Tags: matrices, cv.complex-variables, matrix-analysis, global-optimization

Let $A = [a_{ij}]_{n\times n}$ be a Hermitian matrix, such that $|a_{ij}| =1$ for $i \neq j$, and $a_{ii} = 0$ for each $i$.
I am interested in a tight lower bound of $\|A\|_*:=\sum_{i=1}^n |\lambda_i(A)|$, where $\lambda_i(A)$'s are eigenvalues of $A$.

Note that, 
by minimizing $\sum_{i=1}^n |\lambda_i|$ over two constraints $\sum_{i=1}^n \lambda_i = 0$ and $\sum_{i=1}^n \lambda_i^2= n(n-1)$, one can obtain $\sqrt{2n(n-1)}$ as a lower bound. But it seems that isn't tight.

On the other hand, if $A := J - I$ (all ones matrix minus identity), then $\sum_i |\lambda_i(A)| = 2(n-1)$.

Is it true that $2(n-1)$ is actually a lower bound (for large enough matrices, say $n \geq 10$) ?

**Remarks:**

- As Alex's answer below, the minimum of trace norm of such matrices may be less than $2(n-1)$, even for arbitrarily large matrices.
- But, as a comment of @fedja, the minimum is $(2+o(1))n$ as $n\to\infty$.

**Added:**

- In the particular case, when $a_{ij}=±1$, the lower bound holds. See [this answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/309214/53059) below, for an overview of the proof.

Comment: @ChristianRemling Thanks - I deleted my misguided comment, of course in my approach I was ignoring the diagonal terms which give an $O(n)$ "correction" to my estimate of the trace norm.

Comment: @YemonChoi: But the idea may have been spot on, I'm also curious now what happens for random $\pm 1$'s (or complex $a_{jk}$'s with random phase).

Comment: Could you say a bit more about how your minimization argument works? Having thought a bit more about my earlier deleted comment, I realised I'm still confused about something

Comment: @YemonChoi:  First note that eigenvalues of such $A$s satisfy constraints of the mentioned minimization problem. Moreover, minimum value  $\sqrt{2n(n-1)}$ obtained with some calculation, shows that $\lambda_i$s are optimal only when just two of them are non-zero. I didn't see your deleted comment and I am curious about it.

Comment: Thanks Mahdi. In my comment, I was picking the entries to be $\pm 1$ at random and trying to exploit the fact that with high probability you get matrices whose spectral radius is $O(\sqrt{n})$. But this doesn't seem to help with finding the extremal cases, which is what you are looking for

Comment: If we can show that every matrix $A$ of the form you describe satisfies $\inf\{ \Vert A-D\Vert_{\rm op} : D \hbox{ is diagonal} \} \leq n/2$ then the answer to your question is positive. In particular, we win if the spectrum of $A$ is supported in an interval of length $\leq n$. But I haven't managed to prove this (although it does hold for $A=J-I$).

Comment: Another cheap observation is that the minimum is $(2+o(1))n$ as $n\to\infty$, so the conjecture is quite plausible.

Comment: @YemonChoi: In general, the spread of such $A$s (i.e. $\lambda_{max} -\lambda_{min}$)  is not $\leq n$ (even for arbitrarily large matrices). But your $\inf$ argument may be useful. Could you please explain more about it?  Why, if $\inf \cdots \leq n/2$, then the problem will be solved? Thanks, Yemon.

Comment: Thanks, @fedja. The approach which gives your observation is valuable. Can you explain more about your approach?

Comment: If one restricts attention to circulant matrices then the problem begins to closely resemble the Littlewood problem, see e.g. https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0601565

Comment: @Mahdi I can, but you'll be severely dissatisfied. As of now, it uses Ramsey theory, so the least $n$ for which I can guarantee that my $o(1)$ is less than $0.6$ (just to beat your trivial lower bound) far exceeds the number of particles in the Universe. I'm trying to find something more palatable but so far failing...

Comment: @fedja: However, your observation was interesting,  and your attempt to give a better convergence rate is highly respected.

Comment: @Mahdi Could you ask the circulant question as a separate question, especially since you are now no longer assuming self-adjointness? I don't think it is good to have excessive editing of a single question

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, it is not; in fact, $2(n-1)$ is a local *maximum*.

Let $B$ be a Hermitian matrix such that $|B_{ij}|=1$ and $B_{ii}=1$. We denote its eigenvalues by $\mu$ (not to confuse them with eigenvalues of $A$). It is easy to see that always $\mu\le n$: if $(x_1,\dots,x_n)$ is an eigenvector and $|x_i|=\max_j|x_j|$ then
$$|\mu x_i|=\left|\sum_j B_{ij}x_j\right|\le \sum_j |x_j|\le n|x_i|.$$

If  $A=B-I$ then
$$\sum_i |\lambda_i|=\sum_i |\mu_i-1|.$$
In the case $B=J$ we have $\mu_1=n$ and $\mu_i=0,2\le i\le n$, hence
$$\sum_i |\lambda_i|=2(n-1).$$
If $B$ is not much different from $J$ then we still have one large eigenvalue $\mu_1$ and plenty of small ones, $\mu_i<1,2\le i\le n$. In this more general case
$$\sum_i |\lambda_i|=\mu_1-1+\sum_{i=2}^n(1-\mu_i)=2(\mu_1-1)\le 2(n-1).$$ 
Naturally, even in a vicinity of $J$ it won't always be an equality.

Comment: Regarding the updated version: for $n=2$ all matrices $A$ of the required form have eigenvalues $\pm 1$, so they all have trace norm $2$. Can you show an explicit example for $n=3$ with trace norm strictly less than $4$?

Comment: @ Yemon Choi: If $\mu=n$ then all $x_i$ must have  the same absolute value.  Then we may modify $B$ taking the conjugate of it by a diagonal unitary matrix and turning  the eigenvector into $(1,1,\dots,1)$. It follows that $B$ in this case must be conjugate to $J$.

Comment: Actually, this is a complete answer to my question. But the problem still is open, when the phase of $a_{ij}$s are chosen from a finite discrete set containing zero (In  particular, when $a_{ij} = \pm 1$). That cases may be related to the Littlewood problem when $A$ is a circulant matrix, according to the comment of Tao above.

Comment: I agree. But this would be a question from number theory, which I do not know much of.

Comment: @AlexGavrilov Thank you for the explanation of this case, but this doesn't seem to answer my question. You say that $2(n-1)$ is a local maximum but don't give examples where inequality is strict, and my point was that for $n=2$ inequality can't be strict. So what are some explicit numbers for $n=3$ (or $n=4,\dots$) where inequality is strict?

Comment: For $n=3$ any matrix with $B_{12}B_{23}\neq B_{13}$ would do. (For example, $B=J$ except $B_{13}$.)

Comment: @Alex Gavrilov Are you changing $B_{31}$ along with $B_{13}$? If you don't do that, which violates the assumptions of the question, then it's easy.

Comment: @Alex Gavrilov : Your last comment is wrong : choose $B_{12} = B_{23} = 1$, $B_{13} = -1$ . But your answer is right.

Comment: @jjcale I think Alex was only talking about small perturbations since his argument is about showing we have a local maximum. But taking $B_{12}=B_{23}=1$ and $B_{13}=i$ should work. Indeed it seems this matrix attains the weaker lower bound in Mahdi's original post.

Comment: @Yemon Choi : This matrix attains the lower bound $\sqrt{2n(n-1)}$.

Answer (score 3):

This is merely to expand on one of my comments above.
$\newcommand{\Tr}{{\rm Tr}}$
$\newcommand{\snorm}[2]{\Vert#2\Vert_{(#1)}}$

We recall that for any complex $n\times n$ matrix $X$, the trace norm of $X$ is equal to $\sup\{ | \Tr(XY^*) | \}$ where the supremum is taken over all $n\times n$ complex matrices $Y$ satisfying $\snorm{\infty}{Y}\leq 1$. Here $\snorm{\infty}{\cdot}$ denotes the operator norm, a.k.a. the largest singular value.

Now suppose $A$ has all diagonal entries equal to zero, and let $D$ be any diagonal matrix. Then

$$ \Tr(A (A+D)^*) = \sum_{j,k} A_{jk}\overline{(A_{jk}+D_{jk})} = \sum_{j\neq k} |A_{jk}|^2 = \snorm{2}{A}^2 $$

where $\snorm{2}{\cdot}$ denotes the Hilbert-Schmidt norm, a.k.a. the Frobenius norm.

Consequently $\snorm{2}{A}^2 \leq \snorm{1}{A} \inf_D \snorm{\infty}{A+D}$. If we impose the further constraint that $|A_{jk}|=1$ for all $j\neq k$ then the LHS of this inequality is equal to $n^2-n$, and so

$$ \snorm{1}{A} \geq n(n-1) \cdot\left( \inf_D \snorm{\infty}{A+D} \right)^{-1} $$

Answer (score 2):

In the special case $a_{ij} = \pm 1$, $2(n-1)$ is a lower bound, for every $n>0$.

As a comment by T. Tao above, the problem  resembles 
         the sharp Littlewood conjecture on the minimum of
         the $L^{1}$-norm of polynomials (on the unit circle
         in the complex plane) whose absolute values of
         coefficients are equal to $1$. In
         the special class of polynomials with $\pm 1$
         coefficients, Klemes proved the sharp Littlewood
         conjecture (see [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/303091/l1-norm-of-littlewood-polynomials-on-the-unit-circle)).

> The proof of Klemes gives us the following equality, for an $n\times m$
>    matrix $A$ with singular values $\sigma_1,\ldots,\sigma_{r}$ and for $ 0 \leq p \leq 2 $:
>            \begin{equation*}  \sum \limits_{i=1}^{r} \vert \sigma_{i} \vert^p= C_p \int_{0}^{\infty} \log \left(1+\sum \limits_{k=1}^{r}
>  S_{k}(A^*A) t^{k} \right)t^{-\frac p2 -1}dt,
>    \end{equation*}  where $S_k(A^*A)$  stand for the sum of the determinat of $k\times k$ principle  submatrices of $A^*A$ and  $C_p$ is a constant depenting on $p$.

When $A$ is Hermitian, singular values are equal to eigenvalues and by obtaining a  "good" lower bound for  $S_{k}(A^2)$, when $A$ is a matrix of the form described in the question, we can establish the lower bound in the special case $a_{ij} = \pm 1$.