# $L^1$ norm of Littlewood polynomials on the unit circle

Tags: cv.complex-variables, polynomials, fourier-analysis

A Littlewood polynomial is a polynomial with coefficients from $\{ 1, -1\}$ and the set of Littlewood polynomials with degree $n$ is denoted by $\cal{L}_n$.

I'm interested in a "good" lower bound on the $L^1$-norm of Littlewood polynomials on the unit circle in the complex plane.(which I denote by $\|\cdot \|_1$) To be more precise, consider the polynomial $p(z) = 1+z+\cdots+z^n$, what can be said about 
$$a_n = \frac{\min_{q\in \cal{L}_n} \| q\|_1}{\| p\|_1}.$$
Does $a_n \to 1$ as $n\to \infty$?

Comment: There seems to be some missing information: is ${\mathcal L}_n$ the set of Littlewood polynomials of degree $n$?

Comment: Computation for $n\leq 9$ suggests strongly that $a_n=1$ for all $n$.

Comment: http://www.mathnet.ru/php/archive.phtml?wshow=paper&jrnid=aa&paperid=919&option_lang=en

Comment: @fedja: a nice reference! Another  interesting case is when considering polynomials whose absolute value of the coefficients  are all  equal to 1.  Do you know is there any  similar result in this case?

Comment: In the above comment, I'm mean polynomials with complex coefficients.

Comment: @Mahdi It has been conjectured by Littlewood that the answer is the same but AFAIK it is still open in general.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The link in Fedja's comment shows that $a_n=1$ for all $n$.  I will just add the following formula:
$$
 \|p\|_1 = \begin{cases}
  \frac{2\pi}{n+1} + 4\sum_{k=1}^{n/2}\tan\left(\frac{\pi k}{n+1}\right)/k
    & \text{ if $n$ is even } \\
    4\sum_{k=1}^{(n+1)/2}\tan\left(\frac{\pi(k-\tfrac{1}{2})}{n+1}\right)/(k-\tfrac{1}{2})
    & \text{ if $n$ is odd }
 \end{cases}
$$
or in more machine-friendly form:

```
b := proc(n)
 if modp(n,2) = 0 then
  4*add(tan(Pi*k/(n+1))/k,k=1..n/2) + 2*Pi/(n+1);
 else
  4*add(tan(Pi*(k-1/2)/(n+1))/(k-1/2),k=1..(n+1)/2);
 fi;
end:
```

The proof is somewhat intricate, but all the ingredients are basically elementary.  This gives a nice smooth graph for $\|p\|_1$ against $n$, as shown below.  I haven't found a good asymptotic formula.

[image]