# Asymptotic behavior of an integral depending on an integer

Tags: real-analysis, ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, integration, asymptotics

A friend of mine, obtained a lower bound for the trace norm of matrices described in [this question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/302424/is-this-lower-bound-for-a-norm-of-some-complex-matrices-true) (for the special case $a_{ij} = \pm 1$). That lower bound is $ \frac{f(n)}{2\pi}$ where
$$
f(n) := \int_0^\infty \log\left( \frac{(1+t)^n +(1-t)^n}{2} +n(n-1) t(1+t)^{n-2}\right)t^{- 3/2} \ \mathrm{d}t
$$
Numerical computaions suggest that 
$$ f(n) = 4 \pi n + o(n) $$
How to justify it? Moreover, is it possible to obtain a good rate of convergence?

Comment: Does anything useful happen if you apply L'Hospital's rule and differentiate under the integral sign?

Comment: @NateEldredge The function under integral divided by $n$ converges pointwise to $log(1+t)$ but it seems that there is no dominating function to use convergence theorems for integrals.

Comment: For $n=2,3,4,5$ this is  $4\pi, 4\sqrt{3}\pi, 4\cdot (2.782...)\pi,4\cdot 3.65\pi$, interesting..

Comment: Can't you just consider the difference $f(n) - 4n\pi = f(n) - \int_0^\infty \log((1+t)^n)t^{-3/2}\,dt$, combined into a single integral that looks like $\int_0^\infty \log(g(n,t))t^{-3/2}\,dt$, where $g(n,t)$ is bounded below away from $0$ and bounded above by say $n^2$? That would show that $f(n) = 4n\pi + O(\log n)$.

Comment: @GregMartin: Thanks. It's a good idea.

Comment: @GregMartin In fact using this idea and and a change of variable $nt=u$ gives $f(n)=4\pi n +O(1)$.

Comment: Something is fishy. For large even $n$, if I divide the expression under the logarithm by $(1+t)^n$, I get $1+\frac12[(\frac{1-t}{1+t})^n-1]+n(n-1)t\frac{1}{(1+t)^2}\ge 1+\frac 12(-2tn)+\frac 14n(n-1)t$ for $t\le 1$, which is never below $1$ and tends to $+\infty$ as $n\to\infty$. The integrals from $1$ to $\infty$ are uniformly bounded from below, so you get *more* than $4\pi n$, which is impossible since you have an example of a matrix giving $2n-2$. What am I missing?

Comment: @fedja: Note that in the comment of Greg, there is a typo. Actually, we have $\int_0^{\infty} \log((1+t)^n)t^{-3/2}dt = 2n\pi$

Comment: numerically it seems that $f(n)=4\pi n-6\pi+O(1/\sqrt{n})$

Comment: My response now contains a proof that $4\pi n-6\pi<f(n)<4\pi n-2\pi$.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is an improvement of my previous post. I claim that
$$4\pi n-6\pi<f(n)<4\pi n-2\pi.$$
Starting from
$$f(n)-2\pi(n-1)=\int_0^\infty \log\left(\frac{1+t}{2}+\frac{1+t}{2}\left(\frac{1-t}{1+t}\right)^n+n(n-1)\frac{t}{1+t}\right)\,t^{-3/2}\,dt,$$
we see that
$$f(n)-2\pi(n-1)<\int_0^\infty \log\bigl(1+n^2 t\bigr)\,t^{-3/2}\,dt=2\pi n.$$
Hence the upper bound $f(n)<4\pi n-2\pi$ follows. For the lower bound, we assume $n\geq 2$ without loss of generality, and we start from
$$f(n)-2\pi(n-2)=\int_0^\infty \log\left(\frac{(1+t)^2}{2}+\frac{(1+t)^2}{2}\left(\frac{1-t}{1+t}\right)^n+n(n-1)t\right)\,t^{-3/2}\,dt.$$
Combining this with the inequality
$$\frac{(1+t)^2}{2}+\frac{(1+t)^2}{2}\left(\frac{1-t}{1+t}\right)^n>1-(n-1)t,$$
which can be verified for $t<1/(n-1)$ and $t\geq 1/(n-1)$ separately, we see that
$$f(n)-2\pi(n-2)>\int_0^\infty \log\bigl(1+(n-1)^2t\bigr)\,t^{-3/2}\,dt=2\pi(n-1).$$
Hence the lower bound $f(n)>4\pi n-6\pi$ follows also.